# Rewriting directory into a query parameter in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I converted a website I'm building into a web view app in iOs.

I would like to track visitors that use the app instead of the website by adding a directory to my URL.

For instance, the "about" page URL would go from "https://example.com/about/" to "https://example.com/app-ios/about/"

My question is how to write an htaccess rule that tells my server to go to the path **"/about/"** and skip the **"/app-ios/"** directory?

Also, I'd like to add `?app=app-ios` in my query parameters.

The most promising thing I found was this :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^search/node/(.+)$ /search/node/?app=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

But I'd need to specify what comes before "foo".. In my case, "app-ios" is at the beginning of the request uri, always.

Plus I don't want a redirection. I just want my server to read `/app-ios/something/other-thing/` as `/something/other-thing/?app=ios`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, could you share what you already tried?

Comment: Hello and thank you. I tried first to redirect all to index.php in the /app-ios/directory and work from php, but this gave several issues, notably for .css and .js files.

The most promising thing I found was this : 
RewriteEngine on
#2)internally redirect "/search/node/foo" to "/search/node/?find=foo"#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/node/(.+)$ /search/node/?find=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

But I'd need to specify what comes before "foo".. In my case, "app-ios" is at the beginning of the request uri, Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one question for tracking I would recommend to make this over a Query Parameter (as you wrote) like `?client=ios`, but this might be an own opinion.
For rewriting the URL you could do the following:

to remove from the IOS from the URL (not tested):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)ios/(.*) $1/$2?client_id=ios&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: Hello and thanks. This doesn't seem to work, it redirects me to my main index. I entered the url : "example.com/app-ios/fr/" it redirected me to "example.com/?app=app-ios".

I want it to lead to "example.com/fr/?app=app-ios

Comment: I just posted pseudo code you have to replace it with the full url: `/app-ios/` instead of `ios` this should then actually work

Comment: Of course I did! That's the code I entered : 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app-ios/(.*)$ /?app=app-ios&$1 [L

Comment: One moment let me quickly test on my Apache :-)

Comment: I think the idea would be to capture only from the url and not the uri (path without the query string), then to rewrite the url and to add after that the query parameter to the query...

Comment: Thanks Ghovat. This gives me a 404. I'll investigate!

Comment: empty GET? you mean redirecting to `/` or the client_id param is empty?

Comment: So this led to a 404. I printed the $_SERVER and the $_Get arrays to check what was happening. The URL didn't change and the GET array was empty

Comment: Ok so the trick is to remove the opening slash! This worked : RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)ios/(.*) $1/$2?client_id=ios [L]
However, it leaves me with a problem: other parameters are not recognized… Like /ios/about/?info=hello only returns ?client_id=ios in GET array...

Comment: RewriteRule (.*)ios/(.*)?(.*) $1/$2?client_id=ios&$3

I thought of this but no success...

Comment: what is the error? You might want to put also the rest of the url (params) with: &%{QUERY_STRING}, note than you also have to change [L] to [NC,L]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ghovat, have a nice weekend!